# Creating POSIX group without members in LDAP

Tags: openldap, slapd

I am running OpenLDAP database with activated rfc2307bis schema. I'm trying now to load new groups in my testing instance (Debian) and everything works fine. With the old rfc2307 (NIS) schema, it was not necessary to specify members of a group (`memberUid` attribute). Now, when I need to use `groupOfNames` with one of these posixGroups, I am forced to specify at least one member of that group. How I can prevent this (more or less) redundant information and what is the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the right solution using `groupOfEntries` class which is defined in this [draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-findlay-ldap-groupofentries-00). The `groupOfEntries` has the same attributes as `groupOfNames` only modifies the use of `member` attribute which is now optional.

Answer (score 1):

An option out of core schema is to use `organizationalRole` and `roleOccupant`.

> dn: cn={0}**core**,cn=schema,cn=config
>       olcAttributeTypes: {29}( 2.5.4.33 NAME **'roleOccupant'** DESC 'RFC2256: occupant of role' **SUP distinguishedName** )
>       olcObjectClasses: {6}( 2.5.6.8 NAME **'organizationalRole'** DESC 'RFC2256: an organizational role' SUP top STRUCTURAL **MUST cn MAY** ( x121Address $ registeredAddress $ destinationIndicator $ preferredDeliveryMethod $ telexNumber $ teletexTerminalIdentifier $ telephoneNumber $ internationaliSDNNumber $ facsimileTelephoneNumber $ seeAlso $ **roleOccupant** $ preferredDeliveryMethod $ street $ postOfficeBox $ postalCode $ postalAddress $ physicalDeliveryOfficeName $ ou $ st $ l $ description ) )

---

`groupOfEntries` is likely to be preferred as some software may expect `member` and not be easily reconfigurable.